# check which columns have different values after grouping by

Tags: postgresql

I have a dataset like this:

```
host_id binary_id service binary_date region binary_path ......
1       2         hello   05-06-2012  US     /bin/usr
1       2         hello   08-09-2022  US     /bin/usr
2       3         another 08-09-2026  UK     /bin/java
```

`host_id,binary_id,service` is the group I'm interested in, `binary_date region binary_path` is a subset of many columns I have in this table, the table has approximately 50 columns.
I would like to check which of the 50 columns have different values after grouping by `host_id,binary_id,service`. So for example in this scenario I would get the `binary_date` column since this is the only column which has different values after grouped on.

Expected result would be:

```
host_id binary_id service binary_date region binary_path ......
1       2         hello   05-06-2012  null   null
1       2         hello   08-09-2022  null   null
```

You can see that in this case only the `binary_date` contain the different values, the other columns `region,binary_path` are null because the values are exactly the same across the rows in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to do it :

`row number()` returns a unique id within a partition; this unique number is used to determine whether or not a row has different values within the same partition, if count per partition equals total of row numbers, a change has occurred, otherwise, null is returned.

```
with cte as (
   select *, count(1) over (partition by host_id, binary_id, service) as count_,
             row_number() over (partition by host_id, binary_id, service, binary_date) as rn_binary_date,
             row_number() over (partition by host_id, binary_id, service, region) as rn_region,
             row_number() over (partition by host_id, binary_id, service, binary_path) as rn_binary_path
   from mytable
)
select host_id, binary_id, service, 
      case 
        when count_ = sum(rn_binary_date) over(partition by host_id, binary_id, service) 
        then binary_date 
      end as binary_date,
      case 
        when count_ = sum(rn_region) over(partition by host_id, binary_id, service)
        then region 
      end as region,
      case 
        when count_ = sum(rn_binary_path) over(partition by host_id, binary_id, service)
        then binary_path 
      end as binary_path
from cte
where count_ > 1
```

Result :

```
host_id binary_id   service     binary_date region  binary_path
1       2           hello       2012-06-05  null    null
1       2           hello       2022-09-08  null    null
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/iEsblsnD)

Comment: Very nice, thanks. I was just wondering it would get extremely verbose to do that for 50 columns. If I don't want to spell out all columns, i would then need to implement some dynamic sql right?

Comment: That’s correct, a function can do the trick